# Please keep calm and wait for the right time until

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense

Which of the following sentence is grammatically correct?

**1.** Wait for the right time until the experiments **are** done.

**2.**  Wait for the right time until the experiments **will be** done.

Comment: Neither sentence is correct. You can say *wait until the experiments are done.* Or *wait until the right time after the experiments are done.* But **the right time until** shouldn't be used . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is correct. **"Until"** cannot be followed by the *future tense*, you should use the present form of the verb in order to refer to the future events.

"Until as a conjunction" according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/until):

> We use present verb forms to refer to the future after until:
>
> - I can’t wait until the summer holidays **begin**.